# SQL: Unrecognized name: employees at [9:3]

Tags: sql

I am currently working on using inner joins in SQL, I have attempted to used aliases to fix  this problem but it just changes the name that is "unrecognizable". Database name is employee_data. Table names are employees and departments. The error is being picked up on the last line of code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
employees.name as employee_name,
employees.role as employee_role,
departments.name as department_name
FROM
`project-1-357623.employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN employee_data.departments 
ON
employees.department_id = departments.department_id;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you join with `project-1-357623.employee_data.departments` ?

Comment: Also, not sure what database environment you're using, but you have the `FROM` table name in backticks but not the `INNER JOIN` table name.

Comment: That does not sound like a standard `SQL` question, you may need to expose the RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please try this code

```
SELECT employees.name as employee_name,
employees.role as employee_role,
departments.name as department_name
FROM employees
INNER JOIN departments
ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: Table "departments" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table). this is the error message

Answer (score 0):

Please try. This worked for me

```
SELECT
employees.name as employee_name,
employees.role as employee_role,
departments.name as department_name
FROM
 project-1-357623.employee_data.employees
INNER JOIN 
employee_data.departments ON
employees.department_id = departments.department_id;
```

Or also:

```
SELECT
    employees.name as employee_name,
    employees.role as employee_role,
    departments.name as department_name
    FROM
     employee_data.employees
    INNER JOIN 
    employee_data.departments ON
    employees.department_id = departments.department_id;
```